What is meant by "Error inserting INFIX" in SML Code?
Um... new to SML, still getting my feet wet.
MRE:
Exception Failure

fun max(a,b) =
        if a-b > 0 then
                a
        else
                b

fun knapsack(0,xs) = 0
  | knapsack(a,[]) = raise Failure
  | knapsack(a,(x,y)::xs) =
                if y > a then
                        knapsack(a,xs)
                else
                        max(knapsack(a,xs),x+knapsack(a-y,xs))

fun main() =
        let
                (*(value,weight)*)
                val l = [(20, 9), (17, 8), (14, 7), (10, 6), (8, 5), (6, 3)]
                val c = 20
        in
                knapsack(c,l)
        end

Error:
knapsack.sml:1.2 Error: syntax error: inserting  INFIX
/usr/lib/smlnj/bin/sml: Fatal error -- Uncaught exception Compile with "syntax error" raised at ../compiler/Parse/main/smlfile.sml:15.24-15.46

I'm guessing the :: operator is the culprit, but I can't figure out what is wrong.

Exception Failure is a syntax error. SML is case sensitive, and it should be "exception". (The syntax error messages from SML/NJ are very confusing - it usually tells you what it's trying to do to recover from a problem rather than what the problem is.)

On a side note, a - b > 0 is more commonly written a > b, as you did in knapsack.

@molbdnilo, thank you! What has that got to do with INFIX operators though? I swear SML and Clojure produce near incomprehensible error messages.

I'm afraid it's mostly a mystery to everyone except the few people who wrote that part of SML/NJ. (You can probably figure it out if you study the formal syntax of SML in detail for a long time...)

@molbdnilo, there's already not much material available on these error messages and I'd hate to see this post get deleted. Can you write an answer that I can accept? If possible, would you include the links that are usually helpful to understand such error messages?
